# Запятая перед "и всё" в конце предложения: "....(,) и всё"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

В среду приду в последний раз(,) и всё.

Нужна ли запятая перед и?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая ставится:

**В среду приду в последний раз, и всё.**

**И ВСЁ (ТУТ)**, частица (в конце предложения)

Частица «и всё» употребляется в конце предложения (или части сложного предложения) для указания на простоту или достаточность сообщаемого, отсутствие в нем чего-то большего (то же, что «только и всего»), а также (в том числе в форме «и всё тут») **на категорический характер высказывания**.

Перед частицей «и всё (тут)» ставится **запятая, реже тире.**
http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?id=58_819&layout=item